# Error: Exception in HostFunction: packageVersion must be of type 'string', got (undefined), js engine: hermes

Tags: typescript, react-native

I am using React Native typescript version 0.71.8 and realm version is 11.8.0,Once run android platform showing is 'ERROR  Error: Exception in HostFunction: packageVersion must be of type 'string', got (undefined), js engine: hermes' But iOS platform working fine.How i resolve these type issue? please help friends!

ERROR  Error: Exception in HostFunction: packageVersion must be of type 'string', got (undefined), js engine: hermes error need to be fixed